# Is there a way to hide Vive Controller in the SteamVR lobby?

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, htc-vive, openvr

I'm wondering if there is a way to hide the Vive Controller models in SteamVR Lobby.

I'm building an VR overlay app. Which means I have a unity3D project which can access SteamVR and OpenVR APIs etc. Is there something I can do when that project starts to auto-hide my controller models?

So far I have tried using [`OpenVR.System.CaptureInputFocus()`](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/openvr/wiki/IVRSystem::CaptureInputFocus) and [`OpenVR.RenderModels.FreeRenderModel( RenderModel_t *pRenderModel )`](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/openvr/wiki/IVRRenderModels::FreeRenderModel) to no success.

Has anyone achieved this, know of any VR app that achieves this, or if it is even possible?

Many Thanks,

Liam

Comment: Well you can disable the `GameObject`'s (the controllers).

Comment: No I can't. The model is rendered in the SteamVR lobby, not by me in unity.

Comment: Oh okay, so they are not visible while in the lobby, but they are when you run the app?

Comment: No again, SteamVR lobby is an application (created by valve) when it is run the controller models are visible. I am trying to disable them

Comment: And I guess you would not want to make your own lobby?